# DateTimePicker no limita fecha máxima a pesar de le pones dialog.datePicker.maxDate = today.toMs() - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, datepicker

Hola tengo un proyecto en el cual puedes poner fechas pero tengo un problema es que no limita la fecha máxima a pesar de que le he puesto el código para que limite la fecha máxima

```
val today = LocalDateTime.now()
dialog.datePicker.maxDate = today.toMs()
```

El código está aquí https://github.com/Miguel546/datetimepicker/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/luismiguel/datetimepicker/datehour/fragment/DatePickerFragment.kt de la línea 49 a la 50.

Lo que quiero hacer es que limite la fecha máxima hasta hoy dia en el dialogo del timepicker.
Les dejo un gif hoy día es 15/06/2021 y debería tener el máximo limite hasta el 15/06/2021, sin embargo como se ve en el gif deja escoger las fechas que estan arriba del día 15/06/2021 a pesar que le puse el código que está arriba.

[image: datePicker]

Si me pueden ayudar con este problema porfavor.

Comment: En el gif se muestra Mayo, no Junio.

Comment: Buen punto, gracias voy a tener que hacer algo para que se muestre Junio y no Mayo.